# Nexus public repository returns 401

Tags: nexus

I have a self hosted nexus repository which appears to be returning 401s for anonymous users, if I hit:

```
HOST/nexus/content/groups/public/
```

Or:

```
HOST/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
```

In a browser I get:

[image: Access Denied]

My anonymous user configuration is:

[image: User configuration]

What can I do to make these truly public (read only)?

Comment: Check under 'administration/server' in the UI and make sure anonymous access has been enabled there.

Comment: @rseddon Fixed thanks, feel free to post that as the answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under 'administration/server' in the UI and make sure anonymous access has been enabled there.

Comment: Perhaps this is outdated as this settings sections doesn't appear to exist in my recent (2020-06) install